# How can I get Blink-based browsers to let me scroll through the whole content when using perspective?

Tags: html, css, web, scroll, parallax

I’m trying to implement a parallax scrolling effect, and while it works well on Safari and Firefox, Blink-based browsers (i.e., Chrome, Edge, and Opera) keep giving me trouble and I haven’t been able to get them to work. The problem is the content gets clipped, for some reason. Just for testing purposes, this is what I basically have right now:

```
<div class="outer-wrapper>
    <main>
        <article>...</article>
        <article>...</article>
        <article>...</article>
    </main>
</div>
```

Which is styled as such:

```
.outer-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 1px;
    perspective-origin: 0 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

article {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Each article element has a height of 100vh, and main’s height gets correctly calculated to be 300vh, but its container will not show it in its entirety. With the above code, for instance, I can only see the first two articles, and scrolling beyond that is not a possibility on the aforementioned browsers. In other words, Chrome-based browsers will only show two thirds of main (i.e., 200vh), and nothing I have tried for the past few days has been able to resolve it. I’ve also tried setting the perspective and transform’s origins to the bottom right, by the way (which gets rid of some extra blank space on Safari and Firefox), but Chrome-based browsers will keep presenting the same problem.

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening and how I could fix it? I feel like I’ve run out of things to try at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the given code on Edge, Chrome, Firefox, IE11 on Windows10 and Safari on iPadIOS13 and experienced the problem with scrolling to the 3rd article as described in the question on all except Firefox and Safari.

There seems to be some clash with setting perspective and overflow on the same element. Removing the `overflow-x: hidden;` from .outer-wrapper it is possible to scroll to the 3rd article on all these browsers.

As `overflow: hidden` is set immediately afterwards on main I imagine (but cannot know) that this removal will not break something else in the non-test version.

Putting an `overflow-x` into .article also causes no problem.

I have searched for similar problems and there seemed to have been some problems in the past with perspective and various other settings but I've not found one describing this particular phenomenon.

It looks like a browser bug because it's hard to see why overflow should have this sort of affect alongside perspective.